# What is the codomain of the Radon–Nikodym derivative and why$

Tags: measure-theory, density-function, radon-nikodym

My question is regarding the Radon–Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$, when $\nu \ll \mu$ and both measures are $\sigma$-finite. So Wikipedia says in the article about the Radon–Nikodym theorem that the derivative is a function that maps to $[0, \infty)$, i.e., the positive reals including zero. In all the books I have looked in, however, the theorem states that the density is a function mapping to either

1.) $[0, \infty]$,

or to

2.) $\mathbb{R}$

or to

3.) $[0, \infty)$ almost everywhere,

or to

4.) $[0, \infty)$ but there exists a measureable set $F$ such that
$$\nu = \int f d\mu + \int(\infty \cdot \chi_F)d\mu.$$

But nowhere could I find that the density in fact maps to $[0, \infty)$ (without any other side conditions).

Can someone tell me, if what Wikipedia says is correct? And maybe comment on the tfour different codomains, why they are different, and which assumptions for the theorem may be different for each of these. Also can we even say anything that holds for all measurable sets instead of just making a statement that holds almost everywhere?

Comment: If the mesures are positive and $\sigma-$ finite then Wikipedia is right.

Comment: If you assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are positive Radon measures on $R^n$ (with the absolute continuity assumtion), then their R-N derivative is finite $\mu$ - a.e. In fact you have an explicit formula for the derivative: $$f(x) := lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\nu(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))}$$ where $B(x,r)$ is a ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$ (the limit exists $\mu$ almost everywhere and the function is $\mu$-measurable). The proof is in Evans-Gariepy's "Measure theory and fine properties of functions" in the chapter on R-N theorem (they use outer measures, but it's true for measures too).

Comment: why are there then books that say that the derivative maps to all of $\mathbb{R}$? @geetha290krm

Comment: i.e., to negative values as well, and some that say it can also take infinity as a value

Answer (score 1):

Radon-Nikodym derivartive is defined only up to a set of measure $0$. If you replace the value of R-N derivative over a set of measure $0$, it still remains a R-N derivative. So your 3rd option is same as mapping to $[0,\infty)$ since your thrid option says maps to $[0,\infty)$ almost everywhere. I presume a.e., w.r.t measure $\mu$ and you derivative is $\frac{d v}{ d \mu}$ for measure $v << \mu$.

See below from Wikipedia:
[image]

Comment: But is it correct that it only maps to the positive reals? or can it also map to infinity, or to negative values?

Comment: @guest1 On a set of $\mu-$ measure $0$ it can map to anything.

Comment: can you also comment on the other options, i.e., 1), 2) and 3)?

Comment: 1),4) allow R-N derivative to take the value $\infty$ but derivative is $\infty$, i am guessing only on a set of $\mu$-measure $0$ and 2) is for signed measure $v$ (measure of a set need not be positive i.e., $v(E)<0$ is allowed.)

Answer (score -1):

The derivative is finite a.e. for nonnegative, $\sigma$-finite measures.
In the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem
you have the proof of R-N and $\mu$ a.e. finitness of the derivative for **finite** measures.
Then from this they explicitly write down the implication that R-N holds for all $\sigma$-finite measures; that's the point at which they write down the construction of the derivative as a countable sum of derivatives of finite measures with pairwise disjoint supports; it's easy to see that thus the derivative is $\mu$ a.e. finite for infinite measures as well.

The point 4. in your question is equivalent to saying that the derivative is infinite on the set $F$, which by the finiteness and uniqueness of R-N derivative is only true if $\mu(F) = 0$ (for $\sigma$-finite measures!), thus it's kind of a superfluous way of writing this equation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).